# Name 'ftplib' is not defined?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi

Hey guys I've been cleaning up my old code, and I somehow have problems with declaration of ftplib in except block.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PiFtp2.py", line 57, in <module>
except ftplib.all_errors:
NameError: name 'ftplib' is not defined
```

Here is the Code (the entire code because I have no idea where the problem is):

[Link to GitHub](https://github.com/B-Genc/Pi-FTP-Sync/blob/master/PiFtp2.py)

PS: I'd appreciate if someone could tell me how to show code properly on stackoverflow as well :)

Comment: Did you try importing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning of the file you imported only the ftp function from ftplib.
Instead of

```
 from ftplib import FTP
```

use

```
 import ftplib
```

and then change all FTP function calls from FTP(...) to ftplib.FTP(...) (line 51)

Comment: Thanks! a lot! I thought I had a typo or something that I just couldn't see!